# Why do I see two very similar ETFs on my broker?

Tags: etf

When I search for an ETF on my broker's interface I see multiple for the same search that seem to be same somehow but also different?

Can you explain to me the difference between the two that are shown in the image? Can you explain to me also what each part that is separated by `|` character means? What would be the difference in buying one or the other? Would the price be different for example or any other parameter?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you ask your broker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the identifiers under the name: One starts with "SWX" and one starts with "LSE". A quick search will tell you that SWX is the Swiss Stock Exchange and LSE is the London Stock Exchange. The ETF also has different tickers (the second group) but the same ISIN and currency.

The prices for ETFs traded on different exchanges should be virtually identical on each exchange, or only different for a very short time. So there shouldn't be any meaningful difference between the two.

Note that if the *currency* were different it would be a different story.

In this case, I don't see any actual quotes on 0MOO (LSE) so it's possible that it's a bad listing or was removed in favor of the SWX listing.

Comment: I tried to understand what a ticker is but online I only find the electronic device. What does it mean to have two ticker names as you mention above?

Comment: A "ticker" is a short name given to a stock or other financial instrument. For example, Microsoft's "ticker" on the New York Stock Exchange is MSFT. They are not standard across exchanges, so it can be confusing to know exactly what you're looking at.

Answer (score 2):

@Can'tTell, regarding your question about "tickers" in DStanley's answer, by ticker, she means ticker symbol.  A ticker symbol identifies a security on an exchange. An ISIN identifies a security, but the ticker symbol identifies it on a particular exchange, and that ticker symbol can suffer from exchange to exchange.

In your screenshot, under each of the two entries, there is a pipe-delimited line with four fields:

- exchange (SWX or LSE)
- ticker symbol
- ISIN
- currency (EUR)

Note that the two entries share the same ISIN so they are really the same security.  The two entries differ in what exchange they are traded on, and on each exchange, they have a different ticker symbol.

This article talks a little about the difference between ISIN and ticker symbols.
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/isin.asp

(Sorry, but I've left this as an answer because I just joined and don't have enough points to leave it as a comment under your original comment asking about tickers.)